# Specify variable number of decimal places to printf

Tags: c, printf

I'm wondering how I can use `scanf()` to allow the user type in the number of decimal places he wants the answer given to, and how to input this variable into the `printf` format specifier. For example

```
printf("The answer is %.(variable wanted here)f", answer);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use `*` for your field precision specifier, it tells `printf` that it is variable. You then specify an additional preceding `int` argument to tell `printf` the desired precision.

From [`printf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html):

> Instead of a decimal digit string one may write "*" or "*m$" (for some decimal integer m) to specify that the
>          field width is given in the next argument, or in the m-th argument, respectively, which must be of  type  int.

Note that this also works to set the maximum number of characters to print from a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int places = 3;
    printf("%0.*f\n", places, 1.23456789);
    printf("%0.*f\n", places, 6.7);

    char buf[] = "Stack OverflowXXXXXXXX";
    printf("%.*s\n", 14, buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1.235
6.700
Stack Overflow
```

Comment: The `m$` thing is a gcc extension

Comment: @MattMcNabb I wouldn't be surprised if that were true. However, nothing in that man page indicates as such. (They do explicitly mark other features as glibc extensions though.)

Comment: I should have said, it's not in the C standard . Perhaps it's in POSIX or something.